# jQuery.find on newly created elements alert($('<p id="aa">xxx</p>').find("#aa").length);

Tags: jquery

I am trying to lookup elements within a dynamically created element. For some reason this fails. Why does the following return "0"? How to fix this?

```
  alert($('<p id="aa">xxx</p>').find("#aa").length);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('<p id="aa">xxx</p>').find("#aa") // looks inside the element you're holding
```

you want to filter based on the elements in your existing collection:

```
$('<p id="aa">xxx</p>').filter("#aa")
```

and thus

```
alert( $('<p id="aa">xxx</p>').filter("#aa").length );
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) looks inside the child elements of the currently selected element.

> Description: Get the descendants of
>   each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a
>   selector.

In this case, there are no nested elements, only text.